# HTML div becomes unresponsive after reloading by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

Okay here I have a jsp page, in which I have used a jsp code in inflating elements in an HTML table using a loop...Now when i reload this table using AJAX...what happens simply is that it becomes unresponsive...ie...I'm unable to apply the onClick sorting and search bar which were working before reloading..

Here's my coding for the table

```
       <div class="row-fluid sortable" id="tableRow">       
            <div class="box span12" id="teacherTableRow">
                <div class="box-header" data-original-title>
                    <h2><i class="halflings-icon user"></i><span class="break"></span>STAFF TABLE</h2>
                    <div class="box-icon">
                                                <a href="#" class="btn-setting" id="refresh_table"><i class="halflings-icon wrench"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn-minimize"><i class="halflings-icon chevron-up"></i></a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
                      <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>TN</th>
                              <th>TC</th>

                              <th>Actions</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>   
                      <tbody >

                        <%  while(resultset.next()) { %>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td> <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </td>
                                                        <td> <%= resultset.getString(2) %> </td>
                                                        <td class="center"  >

                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
                                    <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>  
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="deleteTeacherData.jsp?tc=<%=resultset.getString(2)%>"  onclick="return deleteTeacher()" >
                                    <i class="halflings-icon white trash" ></i> 
                                </a>
                            </td>

                                                    </tr>
            <% }%>

                      </tbody>
                  </table>            
                </div>
            </div><!--/span-->

        </div><!--/row-->
```

Here is my javascript code which I have tried so far to reload and get it active..

```
          $('#teacherTableRow').load('HOD-page1.jsp #teacherTableRow');
```

I also tried this, but no avail...

```
          $('#teacherTableRow').load('HOD-page1.jsp #teacherTableRow',function(){
              $('#teacherTableRow').on("load",'HOD-page1.jsp #teacherTableRow'});
```

Comment: The answer has to do with how you assign the "click" handlers etc. - that's the code that needs to be fixed. You either need to run it again after you've reloaded the content, or else use event delegation.

Comment: @Pointy...can you explain me how to do it, whether the click heandlers or event delegation???

Comment: How do you set up the column sort controls in the first place? You didn't post that code.